# Finding a date (column header) where the sum of several rows (based on two criteria) exceeds a specific value for the first time

Tags: microsoft-excel

not a native English speaker here so please bear with me.

Here is an adjusted and simplified version of my table
[image]

What I am exactly trying to find is the first date on which the sum of the numbers of a product (in this case product A) exceeds the value of 50 in a specific country (in this case France) for the first time.
The result that should show up is a year (one of the column headers).

So here is what I tried (please refer to my image):

Using this: `=INDEX(C1:J1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(C2:J2+C10:J10>50,0),0))` I get the year in which the cell's values exceed 50 (the solution is 2016). Even though the result is correct there are two things I want to change. First, in the real version of the table, there are thousands of entries, which would require me to click on all of them (that's why I want to use criteria). And the other problem is that I want to use the sum of all prior years too. Ultimately, I am trying to find the year in which the sum of product A exceeds 50 for the frist time (which should be 2013 in my example).

By using: `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A13="France")*(B2:B13="A")*C2:J13)` I find the total amount for product A in France over all years.

So my idea was to combine both formulas to: `=INDEX(C1:J1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(SUMPRODUCT((A2:A13="France")*(B2:B13="A")*C2:J13)>50,0),0))` but this only gives out the value 2010 which is obviously wrong (2013 should be correct).

If there is a more elegant way of doing this or you know how to fix my formula, please leave a comment.

I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=LOOKUP(1,0/(($A$2:$A$4="France")*($B$2:$B$4="A")*($C$2:$J$4>50)),$C$1:$J$1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: But in my table posted above there are two different rows that meet the criteria France and product A (the second one is row nr. 10). I want the year where the sum of these two exceed 50.
(refering to your image) if I add another row under Spain which has France as  country and A as product, it does not sum up the second row with the first one. 
Furthermore, when I use your formula on my bigger table (refer to my image in the original post) I get the #N/A error as a result. 

Even though this does not seem to be the solution I need I really appreciate your comment.